# How can I define a function in C with + (not as a character) in its arguments?

Tags: c, function, arguments

I want to define function `calc` in the way :

```
calc(num1,num2,+)
```

returns num1 + num2

Comment: You can use `enum` to define functionality, say `FUNC_PLUS` but you cannot pass `+` as a  function argument, only `'+'`.

Comment: A naked `+` is an *operator* and as such can only appear as part of an arithmetic expression like `a + b` or `+z` - it can’t appear in a function argument list on its own like that.  Lundin’s approach is the best you’re going to be able to achieve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that with functions but you can write a function-like macro:

```
#define calc(a,b,op) ( (a) op (b) )
```

Examples:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define calc(a,b,op) ( (a) op (b) )

int main()
{
  printf("%d\n", calc(1,1,+));
  printf("%d\n", calc(1,1,-));
}
```

More proper and type safe program design would however be to use function pointer templates instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int opfunc_t (int a, int b);

int calc(int a, int b, opfunc_t* op) { return op(a,b); }
int add (int a, int b) { return a + b; }
int sub (int a, int b) { return a - b; }

int main()
{
  printf("%d\n", calc(1,1,add));
  printf("%d\n", calc(1,1,sub));
}
```

The latter example is generally the preferred way.